# Partially Stringify JSON POST data

Tags: javascript, json, api, post

I need to POST JSON to an API in a way that one node of the JSON is stringified, if I try to stringify a node in JSON the JSON becomes invalid. Below is an example

Server Side Model that needs to be mapped

```
class Data {
  public int id;
  public string items;
}
```

Client Side JSON

```
var itemssData = JSON.stringify({"name" : "item1" , "info" : [{"size" : 7 , "color" : "blue"}]})
var data = {
 "id" : 1,
 "items" : itemssData 
}
```

Now POST data but data becomes invalid due to following structure

```
"{"name":"item1","info":[{"size":7,"color":"blue"}]}"
```

Do I need to encode this data?Is there a performant way to achieve this as items JSON can be very large
NOTE: I cannot stringify the entire model which includes id

Comment: How do you read the posted data? The client code you have included shows a correct way to post it.

Comment: Can you show your server side code please?

Comment: where exactly you are facing problem? this code should post the data properly, and in server `items` property will be a JSON string which you need to read and understand/parse

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to achieve or what your problem is. How are you sending get data (as JSON? URL-encoded?)? If data is sent as JSON, then are you sure itemssData is supposed to be a JSON string, rather than another object? Or maybe your issue is that the server expects multiple items (and hence an array of objects rather than an object)? No one knows, as you haven't provided enough data: what is the format that is expected by the server, what are you actually sending, what is the error...?

Comment: Ok, so the issues is that on server-side the server does not have a fixed data contract for items, so in order to have the flexibility of data contract, it expects the items complex object as a string.
At the same time, it wants the other fields except for items to match the model on the server-side.
Server-side code is a simple controller action method expecting a similar kind of model as shown in the question above.

Data is being posted as application/JSON.